# Problema con mi FULL JOIN

Tags: mysql, inner

## Mi base de datos :

```
CREATE TABLE Departamentos (
    Id int,
    Nombre varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Empleados (
    Nombre varchar(20),
    DepartamentoId int
);

INSERT INTO Departamentos VALUES(31, 'Sales'),
                                (33, 'Engineering'),
                                (34, 'Clerical'),
                                (35, 'Marketing');

INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES('Rafferty', 31),
                            ('Jones', 33),
                            ('Heisenberg', 33),
                            ('Robinson', 34),
                            ('Smith', 34),
                            ('Williams', NULL);
```

Resulta que tengo el siguiente código :

```
SELECT E.Nombre as 'Empleado',D.Nombre as 'Departamento'
FROM Empleados E
FULL JOIN Departamentos D
ON E.DepartamentoId = D.Id
```

Y me da un fallo que es el siguiente :

> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL JOIN Departamentos D ON E.DepartamentoId = D.Id' at line 3

## [<kbd>Ejecutar</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/174)

Sin embargo con el left join y right join me funciona alguien sabe a que se debe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se debe a que el `FULL JOIN` aún no está implementado en MySQL :(

Entretanto, puedes unir un `LEFT JOIN` con un `RIGHT JOIN` para obtener el `FULL JOIN` que buscas:

```
SELECT E.Nombre as 'Empleado',
  D.Nombre as 'Departamento'
  FROM Empleados E
  LEFT JOIN Departamentos D
  ON E.DepartamentoId = D.Id
UNION
SELECT E.Nombre as 'Empleado',
  D.Nombre as 'Departamento'
  FROM Empleados E
  RIGHT JOIN Departamentos D
  ON E.DepartamentoId = D.Id;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+------------+--------------+
| Empleado   | Departamento |
+------------+--------------+
| Rafferty   | Sales        |
| Jones      | Engineering  |
| Heisenberg | Engineering  |
| Robinson   | Clerical     |
| Smith      | Clerical     |
| Williams   | NULL         |
| NULL       | Marketing    |
+------------+--------------+
```

## [<kbd>Ejecutar</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/175)

Comment: muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Te he añadido un ejecutador del siguiente enlace en tu respuestas : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/175